# Why "Foo f(Bar());" can be a declaration of a function that takes type Bar and returns type Foo?

Tags: c++

I met this C++ question:

Question: Is the following a definition or a declaration?

```
Foo f(Bar());
```

Answer: It is possibly either a declaration of a function that takes type Bar and returns type Foo or it is a definition of `f` as a type `Foo`, which has a constructor that takes type Bar. The problem is the syntax for both is identical so to resolve this problem the C++ standard states that a compiler must prefer function declarations to object definitions where it is unable to make a distinction.

-- I don't understand why it can be "a declaration of a function that takes type Bar and returns type Foo"? how come a parenthesis "()" appear in parameter list?

Comment: JFC not this stuff again

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The function `f` actually takes a function pointer to a function that takes no arguments and gives a `Bar`. The type of the argument to `f` is `Bar (*)()`.

This code fails to compile (and we can see the actual type of the argument in the error message):

```
class Foo { };
class Bar { };

Foo f(Bar());

int main() {
  Bar b;
  f(b);
  return 0;
}
```

But this code does compile:

```
class Foo { };
class Bar { };

Foo f(Bar());

Bar g();

int main() {
  f(g);
  return 0;
}
```

The second meaning it could have, as you say in the question, is that you are making a new `Foo` object called `f` and you are calling the constructor with `Bar()` (a new instance of `Bar`). It would be similar to:

```
Foo f = Foo(Bar());
```

In this situation of `Foo f(Bar());` though, the first interpretation is chosen by the compiler.

Somewhat confusingly, if you add another set of parentheses, as in

```
Foo f((Bar()));
```

the compiler picks the second interpretation.

Comment: why the first piece of code does not compile? isn't it the 2nd possibility mentioned in the original post , a definition of f as a type Foo, which has a constructor that takes type Bar?

Comment: @athos because `f` expects a function pointer as first argument. The statement `f(b);`, `b` is not a func pointer in this context.

Comment: @greatwolf i see. this compiler prefers function declarations to object definitions.

Comment: @athos **All** C++ standard compliant compilers must. As you state: *"the C++ standard states that a compiler must prefer function declarations to object definitions where it is unable to make a distinction."*

Comment: @clcto yes. thanks for reminder. i neglected that part.