# How is this a most vexing parse?

Tags: c++, most-vexing-parse

I was going through this [article](http://herbsutter.com/2013/05/09/gotw-1-solution/)

and there is a statement in item 3 saying

```
// C++98 
rectangle       w( origin(), extents() );       // oops, vexing parse
```

how is the above a most vexing parse. If I did something like this

```
struct origin
{
};
struct Rectangle
{
    Rectangle(const origin& s)
    {
    }
};
```

The statement

```
 Rectangle s(origin());
```

works fine and does not resemble a vexing parse. 
Why did the author say that its a vexing parse. Is that a typo or am I missing something ?

Comment: See section 1(b) of the document, it explains these vexing parses.

Comment: Why do you say `Rectangle s(origin());` does not resemble a vexing parse? It is the canonical example of the most vexing parse. What do you think the most vexing parse is, if not that?

Comment: The declaration works fine. Try to *use* `s` and see what happens.

Comment: I understand that it resembles a vexing parse. However I am under the impression that a vexing parse would result in a compile time error. for example for a class foo using it like `foo a();` would give an error while compiling and its a form of most vexing parse.So from what I get is a that a statement could resemble a vexing parse and at the same time compile without any issues. A vexing parse from what I understand is a statement that might resemble a function. `<Return type> functionName (parameters..)`

Comment: The reason we call it *vexing* is because the declaration *doesn't* cause a compile time error. It only causes an error later in the program *if* you use the function.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Rectangle s(origin());` is a vexing parse too. It declares a function `s` which returns `rectangle`, and takes as argument pointer to function returning `origin`. Not sure what you meant by "works fine".

`rectangle       w( origin(), extents() );` declares a function `w` returning `rectangle` and taking arguments: pointer to function returning `origin`, and pointer to function returning `extents`.

For more detail [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27613904/why-foo-fbar-can-be-a-declaration-of-a-function-that-takes-type-bar-and-r?lq=1) or browse the other questions under the [most-vexing-parse](/questions/tagged/most-vexing-parse) tag.

Comment: By works fine I meant that it compiles with no errors. I am under the impression that a vexing parse would give a compile time error. for example for a class `foo` using it like `foo a();` would give an error while compiling and its a form of most vexing parse.

Comment: @James Franco, not until you try to use it like it is an object

Comment: @JamesFranco if it were not a valid declaration, then it would not be a vexing parse.   The "vexing" part is because you tried to write a variable declaration but it happened to be syntactically valid as a function declaration.  Function declarations are legal, obviously.