# Why does the compiler think my object declaration is a function declaration?

Tags: c++, object, declare

I have a HashTable< Customer > as a member in another class.

The constructor for HashTable< T > takes an int value in order to determine the size of the HashTable's array.

```
HashTable(int numItems) { ... } //constructor
```

The following declaration

```
HashTable<Customer> customers(10000); //doesn't call constructor???
```

receives the error "expected a type specifier" underneath the 10000. When I remove the 10000, I receive the error "Function definition for customers not found." This leads me to believe that the compiler is treating my object declaration as a function declaration.

When I declare my HashTable using dynamic allocation,

```
HashTable<Customer> * customers = new HashTable<Customer>(10000); //works
```

there is no confusion with the compiler.

Why does the dynamic allocation work, but not the other?

Edit: Here is a minimal code that has the same issue stated above.

```
#ifndef _BUSINESS_LOGIC
#define _BUSINESS_LOGIC

#include "HashTable.h"

class BusinessLogic
{
public:
    BusinessLogic();
    ~BusinessLogic();
    void start(); 

private:
    HashTable<int> * custom = new HashTable<int>(10000); //works
    HashTable<int> customers(10000); //error
};

#endif


#ifndef _HASH_TABLE
#define _HASH_TABLE

template<class T>
class HashTable
{
public:
    HashTable(int numItems) {
        if (numItems <= 0) {
            throw std::invalid_argument("Invalid HashTable size");
        }
        currItems = 0;

        //B must be the next prime after 2 * numItems
        B = numItems;
    }

    ~HashTable() {
    }


private:
    int B; //size of itemArray
};

#endif
```

Comment: Is the declaration of `customers` within a class?

Comment: It's difficult to tell what's wrong with bits and pieces of code. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31574575/how-is-this-a-most-vexing-parse

Comment: @RetiredNinja, the most vexing parse doesn't apply when the argument is a number such as the one being used by the OP.

Comment: It's partly because `HashTable<Customer> customers(int 10000);` could be interpreted as a function declaration, and the compiler thinks you've forgotten the "int" part.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180172/default-constructor-with-empty-brackets

Comment: I think you're confusing member initialization (which belongs in the member initializer list of a constructor) vs. a  [*default member initializer*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Member_initialization), which you can [read about **here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36600187/whats-the-differences-between-member-initializer-list-and-default-member-initia). The latter requires the `=`

Comment: Shouldn't the `10000` make the compiler realize it is an instantiation? Does `(int 10000)` even have a meaning as a parameter declaration? @Zexus, the link you provided says `MyObject  object(blah); // ok`, which is what I did, is it not?

Comment: I'm wondering if the compiler is smart enough to realize that 10000 couldn't be a variable name (perhaps if you do change it to `int 10000` and then recompile it'll complain about using a number as a variable).  Have you tried `HashTable<Customer> customers = HashTable<Customer> (10000); ` ?

Comment: @Zexus: I doubt any compiler would ever think that.

Comment: @Zexus, `HashTable<int> customers = HashTable<int>(10000);` works! But I still don't understand why `HashTable<int> customers(10000);` does not. It does not appear to be a vexing case because I am not using empty parentheses. I am using Visual Studio in case that matters.

Comment: The compiler is considering this line as the function 'customers' declaration  that returns 'HashTable <int>'

Comment: @Ignat: No, it isn't. That could not possibly be seen as a function declaration.

Comment: @shtuken: In this particular context the opening `(` invariably drives the parser into the "function declaration" branch of the grammar, making the parser to expect a parameter declaration next. But once the parser sees that `10000` the parsing immediately fails, since `10000` cannot be a parameter declaration. That's all there is to it.

Comment: @AnT, thanks for the explanation!

Comment: This isn't the problem, but names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter (`_BUSINESS_LOGIC`) and names that contain two consecutive underscores are reserved for use by the implementation. Don't use them in your code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are not allowed to use `()` initializer syntax when supplying initializers for class members directly in class definition. It requires either `=` syntax of `{}` -enclosed initializer. In your case it would be either

```
HashTable<int> customers{10000};
```

or

```
HashTable<int> customers = 10000;
```

or, if you wish

```
HashTable<int> customers = { 10000 };
```

The last two versions work because your `HashTable` specialization provides an appropriate conversion constructor. If that constructor were declared `explicit`, you'd have to use

```
HashTable<int> customers = HashTable<int>(10000); // or `= HashTable<int>{10000}`
```

in place of the second and/or third variant.

The initializer you are trying to use is actually officially referred to as *brace-or-equal-initializer*. The name suggests the proper variants of the syntax.

Answer (score 3):

You can't provide a default member initializer for a member variable that way.  You can go with either

```
HashTable<Customer> customers = HashTable<Customer>(1000);
```

or

```
HashTable<Customer> customers {1000};
```

or directly in the constructor

```
BusinessLogic::BusinessLogic(): customers(1000) { }
```