# classname classobject(); does not invoke any constructor

Tags: c++, c++11

If I have a following situation:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A {
public:
    A() {
        cout << "Inside A" << endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    A a();
    return 0;
}
```

Why is the constructor not invoked?

Comment: [My attempt at value initialization is interpreted as a function declaration, and why doesn't A a(()); solve it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424510/) is a more appropriate duplicate. [Why “Foo f(Bar());” can be a declaration of a function that takes type Bar and returns type Foo?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27613904/1968) that you linked to is marked as a duplicate of it.

Comment: @Remy Yes. You’re also right that this isn’t actually an MVP, although it’s so similar that even professionals (exhibit A: yours truly) regularly confuse it. It definitely goes in the same direction as far as expected vs actual behaviour is concerned.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I almost rode it off as MVP, too. I had to look up MVP before posting my answer, just to make sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If something looks like a function declaration, the C++ standard requires it be treated as a function declaration.

`A a();` does not default-construct an object `a` of type `A`.  It declares a function `a` that takes no input parameters and returns an `A` object as output.

To default-construct a variable `a`, you need to drop the parenthesis:

`A a;`

Or, in C++11 and later, you can use curly braces instead of parenthesis:

`A a{};`

Comment: Maybe you should mention "Most Vexing Parse" somewhere in the answer as well, for future searches as well as giving OP some keywords to research..

Comment: @JesperJuhl `A a();` is not actually an example of "most vexing parse", which is why I didn't mention it. Though it is commonly confused with "most vexing parse".